# Htmlagilitypack выбрать дочерний элемент

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

```
var td = htmlNode.SelectNodes("td").Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();
<td align="right">
     <img src="templates/images/countmax.png"></td>
```

В переменной `td` cодерджатся только элементы с тегом `td`, однако хотелось бы чтобы тег `img` тоже видел он.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код можно переписать так:

```
var tdElements = htmlNode.SelectNodes("td").ToList();
```

Теперь в переменной tdElements содержится список объектов `HtmlNode`, каждый из которых соответствует элементу `<td>` и содержит всю вложенную информацию. В частности, из коллекции `tdElements[0].ChildNodes` можно извлечь дочерний элемент `<img>`:

```
var imgElement = tdElements[0].ChildNodes.FindFirst("img");
```

И по-прежнему из каждого элемента можно извлечь `InnerText':

```
var innerText = tdElements[0].InnerText;
```